# How to set correct paths for nodejs application launched via forever

Tags: node.js, upstart, forever

i launch my nodejs application using this upstart script via forever, and it works fine. The problem is that when the application create a folder programmatically, it creates on root directory;

/public/**newfolder** instead of /var/www/nodeapp/public/**newfolder**.

Here is my upstar file myapp.conf:

```
#!upstart

#
description "Example upstart script for a Node.js process"

start on startup
stop on shutdown


expect fork


env NODE_BIN_DIR="/usr/bin"
env NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"
env APPLICATION_PATH="/var/www/nodeapp/app.js"
env PIDFILE="/var/run/myapp.pid"
env LOG="/var/log/myapp.log"
env MIN_UPTIME="5000"
env SPIN_SLEEP_TIME="2000"

script
    # Add the node executables to the path, which includes Forever if it is
    # installed globally, which it should be.
   PATH=$NODE_BIN_DIR:$PATH

    exec forever \
      --pidFile $PIDFILE \
      -a \
      -l $LOG \
      --minUptime $MIN_UPTIME \
      --spinSleepTime $SPIN_SLEEP_TIME \
      start $APPLICATION_PATH
end script

pre-stop script
    # Add the node executables to the path.
    PATH=$NODE_BIN_DIR:$PATH

    exec forever stop $APPLICATION_PATH
end script
```

and the api.js that create the folder:

```
newFolder = "public/"+folder_ID; //relative path for new folder
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

mkdirp(newFolder, function(err) { 
    if (err){
        console.log('error');
    }else{
        console.log('new folder');
    }

});
```

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All `fs` module's methods operate relative to the current working directory (cwd) when relative paths are given, see the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system).

Given the above, you need to tell *forever* to start your application with correct working directory - this can be done via the `--workingDir` flag. See the [docs](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line) again.

Comment: Thank you very much. The  --workingDir option solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need use __dirname in your api.js. For example:

```
newFolder = __dirname + "/public/"+folder_ID;
```